# Forwarding VPN clients to internet

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, port-forwarding, ip-forward

I have following configuration.

OpenVPN server on a cloud(Ubuntu 14.04) with static IP( example 50.60.70.80 on eth0). Linux and Windows clients are successfully connected to VPN (VPN static IP's -  10.8.0.1...199 on tun0).

In VPN network i have few Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 clients every with own web interface running on "https://10.8.0.100"

I need some forwarding when user go to 50.60.70.80:105 to open "https://10.8.0.105" or 50.60.70.80:xxx to open "ttps://10.8.0.xxx" for example.

I spend days to read and try few methods without success. Please help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think iptables would do something for you.

First, activate packet forwarding:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Redirect your traffic from 50.60.70.80:105 to 10.8.0.105:80

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 50.60.70.80 -p tcp --dport 105 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.105:80
```

Make the Iptables marquerade the requisition:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for idea but it don't work. Maybe problem is other. I am not sure witch ports are opened! I open manual many ports, but it looks they are not opened. I cannot ping server, vpnserver works now on tcp 443 not on 1194, even i manually open it in cloud settings... Give me please idea:(

Comment: you can check the open ports using http://ping.eu/port-chk/

All you need to know is the ip address and the port the you open to check if is open or closed.